# Lengths and additive invariants which preserve positivity

Tags: ct.category-theory, ac.commutative-algebra, homotopy-theory, homological-algebra, kt.k-theory-and-homology

The [length](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Length_of_a_module) of a module is well-known to be an additive invariant of finite-length modules. That is, if $R$ is a ring and $Art(R)$ its category of finite-length modules, then $length : Ob (Art(R)) \to \mathbb N$ is a function which is *additive* in the sense that for any short exact sequence $0 \to A \to B \to C \to 0$, we have

$$length(B) = length(A) + length(C).$$

Correspondingly, there is a map $length : K_0(Art(R)) \to \mathbb Z$. But this statement forgets the *positivity* property that the length of a module is nonnegative.

**Question 1:** Let $R$ be a ring and $Art(R)$ is category of finite-length modules. Let $l : K_0(Art(R)) \to \mathbb Z$ be a map which carries every (non-virtual) $M \in Art(R)$ to some (nonnegative) $l(M) \in \mathbb N$. Then is $l$ a multiple of the usual length function?

**Question 2:** Are there other interesting examples of categories $\mathcal C$ with maps $K_0(\mathcal C) \to \mathbb Z$ which carry every $C \in \mathcal C$ into $\mathbb N$? How about for other ordered abelian groups as the target?

Comment: For question 1, try $k \times k$ for a field k. For question 2 in a slightly different setting, there's Elliott's theorem.

Comment: Question 1: the objection raised by @JohnWiltshire-Gordon applies whenever $R$ is not local (and nonzero). On the other hand, if $R$ is local with residue field $k$, $Art(R)$ is generated by $k$, so the answer is yes.

Comment: For question 2, you can have a look at Lemma 5.3 of [this preprint](https://arxiv.org/abs/2301.13206), where the group is the value group of a valuation ring.

Comment: @JohnWiltshire-Gordon Thanks, good points! What is Elliott's theorem? I'm searching and seeing some stuff on $C^\ast$-algebras, but I'm not sure that's what you're referring to.

Comment: @LaurentMoret-Bailly Thanks! I'll have to dig into it -- it looks like whatever they're defining is somehow derived from the length function in some "base case". Very interesting!

Comment: @TimCampion Yes, I'm referring to the C^* algebra stuff. There's some characterization of all possible ordered abelian groups $K_0 A$ where $A$ is an AF-algebra. Since all these questions are trivial for semisimple categories, the AF case is a nice next example.

Comment: chasing down references in here: [Decomposition and classification of length functions, Dario Spirito](http://ricerca.matfis.uniroma3.it/users/spirito/preprint/lunghezze-v13.pdf)